# SSRS 2008 Report Manager Error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have just installed SQL Server 2008 including Reporting Services on Windows Server 2003.  I'm having a problem though accessing the Report Manager.  When the Reporting Service is first started I can access it fine but after maybe an hour when I try and access it I get an error saying: Unable to connect to the remote server.

The reporting service is still running at this point.  I can connect to it through Reporting Services Configuration Manager and clicking on the Web Service URL gives a directory listing  (I assume that is correct behaviour).  If I stop and start the service through Reporting Services Configuration Manager then I can access Report Manager once again (although in maybe an hour I will get the same error once again).

I've installed the latest SP1 service pack.  I'm using the same domain account to run all the SQL services.  The report server is set to use the default ReportServer virtual directory, is set to IP address All Assigned, TCP Port 80 and no SSL certificate.  The report manager is set to use the default Reports virtual directory, IP address All Assigned, TCP Port 80 and no SSL certificates.

In the log file I get an error:

Unable to connect to remote server
HTTP status code 500

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?  I've searched the net but haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the anti-virus software on the server that was causing the problem.  After adding the pagefile.sys as an exclusion it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

configure your rs like below link :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839480(SQL.90).aspx

maybe it solve your problem.